# Authenticate domain user to a domain computer when the computer is not connected to the network?

Tags: active-directory, domain, cache, user-accounts

Our organization sends people to remote locations for periods of 45-90 days. The users at these locations need to use client software on a domain computer in order to do there job. Recently we had an issue where we had to replace a user at the remote location and ran into a problem when the new user never logged into the domain computer at the site. My question... Is there any way to authenticate a user to a domain computer that is offline, when the user has no cached profile?

We are not allowed to use local accounts and must use Smartcard with pin number to log in (no username password login).

Comment: Do the remote locations have internet access?

Comment: I think I would recommend DirectAccess, so what OS version is in use?

Answer (score 3):

No.  If you don't provide a network connection to the server that would authenticate the user account, they cannot logon.  One solution would be to send a computer with the person you send to the remote location, and have them logon to the computer before they are offline.